# Patch or Put with new Object

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-data-jpa

In my application I have the following two objects :

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    // ... //
    @OneToOne
    private B b;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String label;
    // ... //
}
```

First, I record object A with b null. After I need to update A with a new object B that does not exist yet in the database so I want to automatically update A and  save B together.
Can you tell me how I can do this operation?

NB : I can not use the B link in the JSON request because object B does not exist yet

Answer (score 0):

You can add ann annotation that tell you class to save on cascade your connected entity

```
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
```

So your class will become

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    // ... //
    @OneToOne
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    private B b;
}
```

You can study about cascade types [HERE](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/), so you can choose the most suitable type for your needing

Comment: In my PATCH method can not convert the JSON request  because "@RequestBody Resource<A>" waits for a link of object B and it finds a json info.
example of json request : 
{ 
      "b":{
              "label":"toto"
            }
}

so with debug always b is null